# Htaccess rewrite with %REQUEST_FILENAME condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I stucked. I need to:

- all request with domain.com/api/... rewrite to `public/` directory
- all others request rewrite to `frontend/index.html`
- but if request is a file, then rewrite just to 'frontent/'

I had two htaccess files:

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**frontend/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Send Requests To Front...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

It was working but now I need to remove the one from `frontend` directory without loosing it's rules. I changed the main `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

# Send request to backend
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

# Send request to frontend
    RewriteCond frontend/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond frontend/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ frontend/index.html [L]

# Request for file
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/$1
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work. I think that this conditions are wrong:

```
RewriteCond frontend/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond frontend/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

because all request (others than `api`) are rewrited to `frontend/index.html` which i mentioned.

Could anybody show me where did I mistake?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: _"REQUEST_FILENAME: The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced."_ - I am guessing that is probably the case here. So you got a path like `/path/to/project/foobar.txt`, and you want to check if `/path/to/project/frontend/foobar.txt` exists, but `frontend/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` actually is `frontend/path/to/project/foobar.txt`

Comment: Try and use `REQUEST_URI` instead: _"The path component of the requested URI, such as `/index.html`"_

Comment: @CBroe These comments answer the question, so should be an answer :)  I also fell foul by thinking `REQUEST_FILENAME` would be just the filename, before I found this.  (Nomenclature is important.)